# 2017 is Almost Here!

Tags: code-golf

**Challenge**

The challenge is simple:

Taking no inputs and output the following message:

```
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   |
```

A number of times equal to the number of hours before or after midnight UTC on 31st Dec  2016.

**Examples**

For example if it is 19:01 UTC dec 31st you should output:

```
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   | 
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   | 
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   | 
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   | 
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   |
```

if it is 23:24 UTC dec 31st you should output:

```
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   |
```

and if it is 1:42 UTC jan 1st you should output:

```
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   | 
 _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   |
```

Clarification: if it is 10-11pm dec 31st you should output two, 11-12pm dec 31st output one, 00-01am jan 1st output one, 01-02am jan 1st output two etc...

**Rules**

- No Inputs
- Trailing lines or spaces are ok.
- Your program should work any time or day I run it (albeit with a large output). For example on jan 2nd at 00:15am your code should output 25 times.

(This is my first Code Golf question so if I have left any thing important out please let me know.)

**This is Code Golf so Shortest bits win**

Comment: Is the number of hours rounded to the nearest integer? If it's within a half-hour of the New-Year-midnight, should there be no output?

Comment: @GregMartin See my edit for clarification.

Comment: What should happen if I run the program on 3 January?

Comment: @betseg ye I just thought about that to. See edit :). It should work the same even though the output will be large.

Comment: Nice first question. About rounding: the number of repetitions is the absolute value of the difference between current time UCT and 0:00:00 of Jan 1st UTC, rounded up. Correct?

Comment: @edc65 Yep so if you are 45mins from 0:00:00 you should output 1 times  if 43hours 15 mins you should output 44 times

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification What about on 0:00:00 of Jan, it should output nothing?

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur I will leave that open, but I very much doubt that any output at 0:00:00 will be seen since it is only that time for one second (at the most).

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Ok great thanks. I'll output `2017` once because it saves bytes :)

Comment: I noticed bits are specified, not bytes. I sense an incoming solution in 7 with an argument in comments about scoring.

Comment: Hey, can you please update the correct answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 107

As an anonymous method with no parameters

Note `1483228800000` is `Date.UTC(2017,0)`

```
_=>` _     __    __
  |   |  | |   |
  |_  |__| |   |
`.repeat((Math.abs(new Date-14832288e5)+36e5-1)/36e5)
```

**Test** This keeps updating every 1 minute, but you'll need a lot of patience to see the output change.

```js
F=_=>`_     __    __
 |   |  | |   |
 |_  |__| |   |
`.repeat((Math.abs(new Date-14832288e5)+36e5-1)/36e5)

update=_=>O.textContent=F()

setInterval(update,60000)

update()
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2 - 97 + 17 = 114 bytes

```python
import time
print'_     __    __\n |   |  | |   |\n |_  |__| |   |\n'*int((abs(time.time()-1483228800)+3599)/3600)
```

Borrowed logic for ceiling from [edc65's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105189/47650).

**Python 3.5 - 116 bytes**

```python
import time,math
print('_     __    __\n |   |  | |   |\n |_  |__| |   |\n'*math.ceil(abs(time.time()/3600-412008)))
```

`math.ceil` returns an integer in `3.x` whereas in `2.x` it returns a float.

Thanks [elpedro](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105189/47650) for saving 3 bytes.

Comment: @ElPedro Thanks. Was about to do that, in my previous solutions I was fiddling with `datetime.now(pytz.utc).timestamp()` which required python 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

## C compiled with Clang 3.8.1 <s>327</s> <s>317</s> 145 Bytes

*172 bytes saved thanks to @edc65*

```
#include <time.h>
t;main(){time(&t);t=abs(difftime(t,1483228800)/3600);while(t--)puts(" _     __    __\n  |   |  | |   |\n  |_  |__| |   |\n");}
```

## Ungolfed

```
#include <time.h>
t;
main()
{
time(&t);

t=difftime(t, 1483228800)/3600;

while(t--)
    puts(" _     __    __\n  |   |  | |   |\n  |_  |__| |   |\n");
}
```

**317 bytes**

*10 bytes saved thanks to @LegionMammal978*

```
#include <time.h>
t,y,w;main() {struct tm n;time(&t);n=*localtime(&t);n.tm_hour=n.tm_min=n.tm_sec=n.tm_mon=0;n.tm_mday=1;w=n.tm_year;if((w&3)==0&&((w % 25)!=0||(w & 15)==0))w=8784;else w=8760;t=(int)difftime(t, mktime(&n))/3600;t=t<w/2?t:w-t;for(;y++<t;)puts(" _     __    __\n  |   |  | |   |\n  |_  |__| |   |\n");
```

## Ungolfed

```
#include <time.h>
t,y,w;
main()
{
    struct tm n;
    time(&t);

    n=*localtime(&t);

    n.tm_hour=n.tm_min=n.tm_sec=n.tm_mon=0;
    n.tm_mday=1;
    w=n.tm_year;

    if((w&3)==0&&((w % 25)!=0||(w & 15)==0))w=8784;else w=8760;

    t=(int)difftime(t, mktime(&n))/3600;
    t=t<w/2?t:w-t; 

    for(;y++<t;)
        puts(" _     __    __\n  |   |  | |   |\n  |_  |__| |   |\n");
}
```

I will add some explanations when I'll be able to.

Comment: Aren't you able to do `n.tm_hour=n.tm_min=...=n.tm_mon=0;`?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Oh yeah, I forgot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) - <s>71</s> 68 bytes

```
*"_     __    __
 |   |  | |   |
 |_  |__| |   |
".Ea412008c.d0 3600
```

Uses the same logic used in my python 3.5 answer.

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2A%22_%20%20%20%20%20__%20%20%20%20__%0A%20%7C%20%20%20%7C%20%20%7C%20%7C%20%20%20%7C%0A%20%7C_%20%20%7C__%7C%20%7C%20%20%20%7C%0A%22.Ea412008c.d0%203600&debug=0)

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Isn't this shorter?